# How can I prevent word-break in table cell (and force table width to increase)?

Tags: html, css, html-table

My situation: I'm making a table for mobile users, and I have a html table.

How do I apply CSS so that

1. All cells (td) are forced to not break words, but break at white-spaces only.  (`white-space: nowrap;` is not an acceptable solution.)
2. All columns should expand in width (ignoring width limit, idc if it overflow, because my  will make it scrollable) to ensure that there's no word-break, but only breaking at whitespaces.

```html
<div style="overflow: scroll;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <!-- some header -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some evenlongertext with words in multiple_lines</td>
        <td>Some supersupersuperlong text.</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- etc., more rows. -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1:**
My table currently looks like this on a mobile screen, for reference:
[image: current table]

I want it to expand in width to make sure there are no word breaking, at the cost of overflowing horizontally.

**EDIT 2:**
Clarification on word wrapping:
I want it to grow, but not to the point that the entire string does not break. e.g. for the string "Some evenlongertext with words in multiple_lines",
it doesn't have to show like
`Some evenlongertext with words in multiple_lines`
, but it can show like

```
Some
evenlongertext
with words in
multiple_lines
```

where there is no break within each word

**Edit 3:**
It looks like the overhead stylesheet for my entire site (which I can't change) has set `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: Sounds like you want the table and columns to grow *and* have text break at white-spaces. I don't know how you can do both. You also said columns should be "ignoring width limit", but where is the limit now?

Comment: @wazz the implied limit of 100% of parent

Comment: The current parent has no limit.

Comment: @wazz updated question to show my current display, not sure why but the div is restricted to 100% of viewport and the table does word-break and not overflow.

Comment: Yeah, your requirements are in conflict. It's not clear what you're after.

Comment: `th, td {width: 33%}` ?

Comment: @A.Meshu i feel like it will still break the words on the current setting. Also, having all the columns fit into the viewport width is not the focus here

Answer (score -1):

You could use each cell as a div, if you use flex-box, it will automatically be responsive, and that is good for mobile apps. Just create another div around all of the cells (divs), and give that div the class `wrapper` or `container`.
This will be your css

```
wrapper {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

.cell {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: why limit the height and width to `100px`?

Comment: this can be something random, it is not necessary, but if you want the cells to have equall height, you better do this